# How to get the path to the current MacOSX SDK when only Command Line Tools are installed?

Tags: macos, sdk, osx-elcapitan, xcode-command-line-tools

We are trying to locate the current platform SDK used by some of our OSX machines (10.11).
On those machines, **only the Command Line Tools are installed**, not the full blown Xcode app.

Looking up on SO, we were able to find the command `xcrun --show-sdk-path`, which prints out an empty line.

On the other hand, `xcrun --show-sdk-version` correctly shows `10.11`.

Is there a way to locate the path to the SDK used by our compilation tasks ?

Comment: Please note the versions; this seems to be specific to the version of XCode (5.0) which was MacOS versions 10.9+

Answer (score 3):

This is very late, but I've only just started grappling with this.

Running on El Capitan, 10.11.6.

```
$ xcrun --show-sdk-version
10.11
$ xcrun --sdk macosx10.11 --show-sdk-path
          << blank line here
```

but

```
$ xcrun --sdk macosx10.12 --show-sdk-version
10.12
$ xcrun --sdk macosx10.12 --show-sdk-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

Just for completeness,

```
$ xcrun --sdk macosx10.13 --show-sdk-version
10.11
$ xcrun --sdk macosx10.13 --show-sdk-path
          << blank line here
```

and

```
$ ls -l /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  170  4 Jun 16:14 MacOSX.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  4 Jun 16:13 MacOSX10.12.sdk -> MacOSX.sdk
```

(isn't that last symlink the wrong way round?)
(no, it’s the way Apple intended, judging by Mojave)

Comment: Fwiw,
`xcrun --show-sdk-version` on my 10.10 -> 10.11❓
`xcrun --show-sdk-path` ->
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOS`
(Xcode 7.2.1).
How to list the SDKs that a .dylib uses, check consistency ?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

The man page says:

> Prints the path to the currently selected  developer  directory.
>   This  is  useful  for  inspection,  but  scripts and other tools
>   should use xcrun(1) to locate tool inside the  active  developer
>   directory.

On a Mac with only the command line tools installed I get:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and xcrun --show-sdk-path gives me the same blank line as you get.